# Equivalent sqlsrv_ for array_push() in PHP, XAMPP, SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

Is there an equivalent code for `array_push()` in `sqlsrv_`? Like `sqlsrv_array_push()`. I'm not sure if it has one, I haven't read a documentation on that code. Is there an alternative for this?

I tried to re-code it, and this is what I've got so far.

EDIT: Added conn.php

```
<?php
$serverName = "XXXXXX\XXXXXX";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXXXX", "UID"=>"XXXXXX", "PWD"=>"XXXXXX");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

EDIT: Added `$and`

```
$and = 'AND YEAR(date) = '.$year;
$months = array();
$ontime = array();
$late = array();
for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE MONTH(CHECKTIME) = '$m' AND CHECKTYPE = 'I' $and";
    $oquery = $conn->query($sql);
    array_push($ontime, sqlsrv_num_rows($oquery));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE MONTH(CHECKTIME) = '$m' AND CHECKTYPE = 'O' $and";
    $lquery = $conn->query($sql);
    array_push($late, sqlsrv_num_rows($lquery));

    $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $month =  date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    array_push($months, $month);
}
```

This is the error that I'm getting.

> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\path\tofile\home.php on line 198

Comment: What is `$conn` and  `$and`? Your query failed, so there's probably a syntax error in the query somewhere. Enable error-reporting and figure out what went wrong.

Comment: No, PHP Driver for SQL Server hasn't such a function. Can you explain why you need such a function? Probably there is another  way to achieve your results.

Comment: @Qirel ````$and = 'AND YEAR(date) = '.$year;```` addendum.

Comment: @Zhorov I'm trying to make a row on all data available for ````array_push($ontime, sqlsrv_num_rows($oquery));````, I use the data to make a chart.

Comment: Use `sqlsrv_errors()` to figure out why the query failed. Clearly the query fails since `$Xquery` is a boolean. I wasn't aware that there was an OOP interface for `sqlsrv_` though.

Comment: @Qirel, thank you. I used the ````sqlsrv_errors()````.  It was the ````$and = 'AND YEAR(date) = '.$year;```` It should be ````$and = 'AND YEAR(CHECKTIME) = '.$year;````! I will update you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanations:**

If I understand your logic, you need to replace `$conn->query($sql);` with [sqlsrv_query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-2017) call. Functions `sqlsrv_?` are part of PHP Driver for SQL Server and are not object oriented.

**Example:**

Next example is based on your code and may help to get your expected results:

```
<?php
$and = 'AND YEAR(CHECKTIME) = '.$year;
$months = array();
$ontime = array();
$late = array();
for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE MONTH(CHECKTIME) = '$m' AND CHECKTYPE = 'I' $and";
    $oquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    if ($oquery === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    array_push($ontime, sqlsrv_num_rows($oquery));


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE MONTH(CHECKTIME) = '$m' AND CHECKTYPE = 'O' $and";
    $lquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    if ($lquery === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    array_push($late, sqlsrv_num_rows($lquery));

    $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $month =  date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    array_push($months, $month);
?>
```

**Notes:**

You may also consider using parameterized queries:

```
<?php
$y = 2019;
$months = array();
$ontime = array();
$late = array();
for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE YEAR(CHECKTIME) = ? AND MONTH(CHECKTIME) = ? AND CHECKTYPE = 'I'";
    $oquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(&$y, &$m), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    if ($oquery === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    array_push($ontime, sqlsrv_num_rows($oquery));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT WHERE YEAR(CHECKTIME) = ? AND MONTH(CHECKTIME) = ? AND CHECKTYPE = 'O'";
    $lquery = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(&$y, &$m), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    if ($lquery === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    array_push($late, sqlsrv_num_rows($lquery));

    $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
    $month =  date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
    array_push($months, $month);
}
?>
```

Comment: This is way better, thank you. All i need now is to set ````$year;```` in ````$y = 2019;```` since it is a drop-down option.

Comment: @pjustindaryll Glad to help! I've added `sqlsrv` tag for future readers. Thanks.